# Does some of accretion disk light make focal points above the black hole poles?

Tags: electromagnetic-radiation, black-holes, curvature, accretion-disk

Does some of accretion disk light make focal points above the black hole poles?[image]

Comment: What I should add to improve the question to not to be closed as there a two 'close'-votes to this question?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly Could some of these focal points be extremely energetic? Could they somehow disturb an astrophysical jet?

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking: could light from the accretion disk become sufficiently concentrated near the axis that it would affect the jet? The physics of astrophysical jets is not my specialty, but I suspect the answer is no. That seems consistent with the answers to the question that was linked as a duplicate. (Apparently the close-votes were because your question was deemed to be a duplicate of that other one, not because anything was wrong with your question.)